# Can't connect to MYSQL linux VMware server (Through MySQL Workbench 8)

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am trying to access MYSQL DB on (Linux VMware Machine) through MySQL Workbench 8 on (Windows Machine), but getting this

Failed to Connect to MySQL at 192.168.100.135:3306 with user root
Host '192.168.xxx.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL Server

Notes:
--> Linux VM IP which mysql is installed: 192.168.100.135
--> Windows IP which I am trying to connect from: 192.168.xxx.x'

Error

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard security configuration of MySQL, that just allows root connections from 127.0.0.1 and not from remote machines.

You can create a new user and grant permissions, as described in https://support.infrasightlabs.com/troubleshooting/host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server/. Replace vScopeUserName with your username, and vScopeServerIP with your source IP address, which will be your Windows IP address in this case.